# What's wrong with this proof?- reverse triangle inequality

Tags: analysis, self-learning

Subtract this inequality $-|y|\leq y \leq |y| $ , from this inequality $-|x|\leq x \leq |x|$ to get $-(|x|-|y|) \leq x-y \leq |x|-|y|$. Using the property $-a \leq x \leq a \implies |x| \leq a$, we obtain $|x-y| \leq |x|-|y|$.

However, the reverse triangle inequality has the inequality sign reversed. I don't understand what's wrong with my proof. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can't subtract an inequality from another and expect to get a valid inequality. For example, $1<2$, $3<4$ but $3-1 \not < 4-2$.

Answer (score 3):

You can't subtract an inequality from another and expect to get a valid inequality.

For example, $1<2$ and $3<4$ are valid,

but $3-1 \not < 4-2$.

Comment: Well, actually you *can*, but one of the inequalities must be reversed, i.e. if $a<b$ and $c<d$, then $a-d < b-c$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!